# How to auto sign-in the user from the universal sign in link?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying that when users of a domain when they are clicking an app in the universal menu, they will be logged in.

This is the universal menu I speaking about:

[image]

This is the settings in the gSuite marketplace sdk

[image]

The problem is that I can't identify who is the user who clicks the link.

I tried following thie help article: https://support.google.com/a/answer/174917?hl=en&authuser=3, but it didn't helped me. (What should I do with the realm?)

I tried to give directly link into oAuth (`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth`), but the user see prompt to choose an account.